# Make the the subviews behave as float works in html

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a grid of views inside a main view. I want the views to float left (and up) and fill the extra space when I change orientation of the iPad. [image: UI, portraid mode]

[image: Landscape mode, how i want it to look]

How can i achieve this?
Im pretty new to core animation and cocoa-touch as such. So any pointers on where to start will also be very helpful.

PS: For some reason I can't seem to upload the screenshots here.

Comment: Can you provide the code block which you have tried?

Comment: Notice how the iPad apps rotate on the main screen.  Maybe try replicate that effect?

Comment: If you can target iOS 6. Look at `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

Comment: I dont have an idea on where to start. I haven't tried out. I found out about a method called layoutSubviews, but don't know how to use it. :-|

Comment: The target is iOS 5. So i guess i can't try that out.

Comment: @theAmatuerProgrammer: I want them to rotate as well as move and occupy the free space.

Comment: There's also https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout/blob/master/RFQuiltLayout/RFQuiltLayout.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `layoutSubViews:`in the end to make the views behave the way I want. Although it doesn provide behavior as specific as float in html. It gives a lot flexiblity the way you want to rearrange the views. It involves a lot of code though to specify where exactly you want the views. But in the end you get the subviews exactly where they want using this method as during all possible chances of layout changes this method is called and I am able specify where I want the views to be.